# How do I use MAX and Count with two table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that needs to count the field Points. Then returns the highest value. This query does that fine however I now want to link another table 'Team(PlayerID) with Player(PlayerID), So it shows the player team details etc. I attempted to do that normally on how you would join table but keep getting errors. I also do not want to use the order by desc - First row only. (Oracle)

Query:

```
SELECT PlayerID, COUNT(Points)
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result!

Comment: where is the team table in your quey? I guess this is only the working query... but how can you expect an answer if you don't show the query that doesnt work ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add the team table onto this. Player.TeamID = Team.TeamID.... All I need to do is add the 'TeamName' which is from the team table. I'm having problems joining that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*, p.* FROM
team t INNER JOIN
(SELECT PlayerID, COUNT(Points)
 FROM Player
 WHERE Points = 1
 group by PlayerID
 HAVING COUNT(Points) = (SELECT MAX(count(Points))
                         from Player
                         WHERE Points = 1
                         group by PlayerID)
) p
ON t.PlayerID = p.PlayerID
```

Comment: You are a genius!! All perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
....
HAVING COUNT(Points) = (SELECT MAX(sub.cp)
                        from (SELECT count(Points) as cp
                              from Player
                              WHERE Points = 1
                              group by PlayerID) sub
                        )
```

Comment: I would like to join the team table and add columns in the query. Player.TeamID = Team.TeamID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.PlayerID, a.TotalPoints, b.[stuff]
FROM (SELECT PlayerID, COUNT(Points)
        FROM Player
       WHERE Points = 1
      group by PlayerID
      HAVING COUNT(Points) = (SELECT MAX(count(Points))
                                from Player
                               WHERE Points = 1
                              group by PlayerID)) a
join TEAM b on b.playerid = a.playerid;
```